# JQuery selecting elements with variables

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take use JQuery to recieve a response which consists of a name value and a score value. The code is supposed to match the response name with a name in a table which displays scores, then updates the score cell in that names table row. Problem is, I dont know how to select the table element.

This is the function:

```
function rollBall() {
var pins = $('#pins').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/ajaxjqjsbowling/play.htm",  
            data: "pins=" + pins,  
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
                    var cname = response.result.currPlayName;
                    var cscore = response.result.currPlayScore;

                $("td#plName [name = cname] + td#plScore").replaceWith('' + cscore);
            }

        },  
        error: function(e){  
          alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }  
      });
}
```

And this is the table code:

```
<table id = "playerslist">
    <c:forEach var="player" items="${players}">
    <tr id = "htmlplayerno"><td> ${player.htmlPlayerNo}:</td><td id = "plName">${player.name}:</td><td id = "plScore" >0</td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table> 
<table>
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate your strings together, it will just be the string `"td#plName [name = cname] + td#plScore"` otherwise. You also need to use classes since there are multiple players and **`id`s need to be unique**.

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
        var cname = response.result.currPlayName;
        var cscore = response.result.currPlayScore;

        $("td.plName:contains('" + cname + "') + td.plScore").html(cscore);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table id = "playerslist">
    <c:forEach var="player" items="${players}">
    <tr class="htmlplayerno"><td> ${player.htmlPlayerNo}:</td><td class="plName">${player.name}:</td><td class="plScore" >0</td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

### Alternate solution

Here is another way that may work.

**HTML**

```
<tr id="${player.name}" >
    <td class="plNo">${player.htmlPlayerNo}:</td>
    <td class="plName">${player.name}:</td>
    <td class="plScore">0</td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$("#" + cname + " .plScore").html(cscore);
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it didnt work. The name cell has an id instead of a class, is that correct?

Comment: Class instead of an id for `plName`, didn't change the HTML. Updated.

Comment: Sorry, its still not working. I tried that, and a couple of variations, but still nothing. I thought it could be the response, but it seems to be ok, this i got from firebug:            {"result":{"strikeMessage":"","currPlayScore":37,"currPlayName":"Mark","currPlayNo":2},"status":null}

Comment: I updated again using :contains to check inside `.plName`, the previous version was checking the `name` attribute.

Comment: Sorry again, still nothing!

Comment: Once more lol, changed `.replace()` call to `.html()` and added another way with modifying the markup.

Comment: Solved! Got rid of the 'if' statement. Not sure what that did though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since id is unique, why not just:

```
$("#plScore").replaceWith('' + cscore);
```

Comment: The problem is that the table has multiple players. The other answers have suggested classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

in Html id is unique. if you have more than one tr you must use class.

```
<tr id="${player.htmlPlayerNo}" >
  <td> ${player.htmlPlayerNo}:</td>
  <td class="plName" >${player.name}:</td>
  <td class="plScore" >0</td>
</tr>
```

then

```
$("#" + ${player.htmlPlayerNo} + " td.plScore").html(cscore);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code is incorrect, the player.htmlPlayerNo part wont work. Shouldnt it be plName instead?